# How can I create unique slugs for url use in web2py?

Tags: url, unique, web2py, slug

I understand I can create a slug by doing the following:

```
db.define_table('product',
    Field('name','string', notnull=True),
    Field('slug','string', compute=lambda row: IS_SLUG()(row.name)[0]),
...
```

Other than the syntax being kind of funky IMO, this works at a creating a basic slug.  However as I want to use the slug as the basis of my URLs I need it to be unique and it's possible for two products to have the same name.  How can I ensure that the slug generated is unique?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about:

```
compute=lambda row: str(row.id) + '_' + IS_SLUG()(row.name)[0]
```

Comment: I didn't think `row.id` was available in a computed field.

Comment: Yes, it is, and it's very useful to have it there.  It enables you to do quite a few nifty things.  If you like the solution and it works, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Does this work for you?  When I do this it causes my entire slug field to be null.